# Invite friend in Facebook app from app dashboard

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Is there a way to invite friends to a new Facebook app, using app dashboard (I mean here: `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/###############/dashboard/`)? Or I must create a page to invite people?

I’m newbie. I have create a new app, without any app page yet. I’m trying do some API call, for which need some users in the app.

Or, as alternative, how can a user, from an app, invite his friends to use that app?

This is how Goodreads manage it:
[image: invite facebook friends from goodreads]
Thanks.

Comment: You can add users to the different app roles via app dashboard, but you can not send normal app invites from there.

Comment: I have added users as tester and as developer, but when I retrive user list from the app I don't see them.

Comment: What do you mean by “retrieving user list from app”?

Comment: With `FB.api('/me/friends...')` I try to retrieve the list of my friends who are in the app. The API retrives only one person, but I have 2 persons as testers/developers.

Comment: They need to have granted the app `user_friends` permission on their end too.

Comment: How can apps like **Fast for Facebook** (Android) see a list of all my friends? I’m sure that when I installed **Fast** no one of my friends granted anything to it

Comment: If they do, and it is not in the context of tagging or inviting, then they are doing stuff that is not allowed. Report them to Facebook.

Comment: This is a side question that can matter: when I use any FB app, the app show me my friend list to invite them. How does it works?

Comment: I don’t know what you are referring to.

Comment: I edited the question to add a sample from Goodreads

Comment: That is just the Send dialog provided by Facebook, that allows the user to chose the recipients. That has nothing to do with the app itself.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog